# Psychic Mediums vs Buddhist Monks

Tags: psychic-powers

Who would have the better handle on how the true nature of reality is organised? For example what karma actually is and and how we discharge our obligations towards it; our free will in selecting a new incarnation. Logic dictates that the more insightful answers come from those who can communicate directly with the spirit world as psychic mediums can. The true role of the Buddhist Monk surely is to facilitate peace on Earth rather than to pontificate on the technicalities of the afterlife. This point by the way is not to denigrate the efforts of Buddhist monks, whom I have the greatest respect for.

Comment: Speculation based on arbitrary premises (the role of monks, someone who can directly communicate with the spirit). For me BSE should be a forum for question with a bit more background and should be bounded to real observations. So I downvote the question (-1)

Comment: You could reformulate the question, perhaps asking whether buddhists regard beings living in other "planes" to be more insightful, or if buddhists believe that just contacting insightful beings makes us insightful (the answer, though, to both questions would probably be "no").

Comment: Firstly welcome. Can you clarify your question? Probably you already know this, but this is a Q&A site. Not exactly oriented toward discussion. Try to write down your doubt clearly so people can answer appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

**Who would have the better handle on how the true nature of reality is organised**?

Buddhist monks.Because they follow the teachings of the Buddha.The Buddha taught Karma and Rebirth.

**Logic dictates that the more insightful answers come from those who can communicate directly with the spirit world as psychic mediums can**

Please elaborate.I got lost at Logic.

**The true role of the Buddhist Monk surely is to facilitate peace on Earth rather than to pontificate on the technicalities of the afterlife**

It's neither.The true role of the Buddhist Monk is to realize nibbanna.

Comment: "You can only find truth with logic if you have already found truth without it." ~ G. K. Chesterton,
English author & mystery novelist (1874 - 1936) :)

Comment: This is illogical but makes sense : ">